# convert mysql query to cake php find

Tags: cakephp

i have a mysql query as below :

```
select * from users  where email='xxx@xxx.com' and password = SHA1(CONCAT(SHA1(SHA1("123456")),salt))
```

i want to convert to cake PHP find using beforSave Function :

```
public function beforeFind(array $queryData) {
           if(isset($queryData['conditions']['User.password'])) {                        
            $queryData['conditions']['User.password'] = 'SHA1(CONCAT(SHA1(SHA1("'.$queryData['conditions']['User.password'].'")),User.salt))';

           }           
           $this->log($queryData);

           return $queryData;
       }
```

the mysql query is run okie but in cakephp find this not work.

Thank for help.

Answer (score 5):

### Don't include plain-text passwords in your queries!

You should **never** do this; you're including plain-text passwords as part of your query and including your 'salt' values as readable string as well.

SQL queries may be **logged** (and backed up), so those log files can contain all this information in readable format!

You should 'hash' the password using *PHP* and use the **hashed** password to query your database

### Hashing passwords via the AuthComponent

First of all, if you're using the AuthComponent, CakePHP will do all this kind of actions automatically; it will look up/identify a user and (if correct) allow you to log-in that user.

See: [Authentication](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#authentication)

To encrypt passwords 'manually', use [`AuthComponent::Password()`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#hashing-passwords-for-digest-authentication) or [`Security::hash()`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/security.html#Security::hash)

I'm in a hurry right now, but if you need more information or an example, place a comment, then I will add that information

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your problem correctly then you want to search for a user with given username and password. You don't need to use beforeSave for this. If you want to encode password then surely you could use beforeFind or IMO you can do it in a single line itself, just before you execute the query.

You can use Cakephp find by query method. Something like this `$this->Users->query("your mysql query");` or if you want to use normal find, that would also work.

```
$user = $this->Users->find('first', array(
    'conditions' => array('Users.email' => $email, 'Users.password' => $password)
));
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: the $password is origin password, but now password field is replaced by sha1(sha1(sha1<'origin_password'>))+ Salt_string), my table has 2 fields : password and salt.

Comment: if it is working as a normal mysql query. then why wouldn't `$this->Users->query("select * from users  where email='xxx@xxx.com' and password = SHA1(CONCAT(SHA1(SHA1("123456")),salt))");` work?

Comment: Please read the information in my 'answer': even if you manage to get this to work, it is **very insecure**

Comment: yeah definitely you should be using Cakephp password encryption methods as they are much more secure. But I think the main question was to search for a user using normal query. wasn't it?

Comment: @Preetam yes, that was the *question*, just realize the requested 'answer' is not always the *right* answer. OP may be looking in the wrong direction because he doesn't know about all the features CakePHP offers